# How does hadoop pass by reference?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

ChainMapper.addReducer & addMapper's 7th argument is pass data as value or reference.
I fail to understand how  data can be passed as references when a reducer can run on a different machine than the mapper.

Hadoop experts please kindly reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Chain` classes add additional `Mapper` transformations before or after a `Mapper` or `Reducer`. It happens within the local computation on a worker. There is nothing about this that requires the keys and values to be serialized, sent to another machine, and processed again. It just happens in-line.

That's why this might be confusing, since we're not used to a `Mapper` seeing literally the same object output by another operation. That would be the more efficient thing, to pass by reference. But it's possible that the code assumes it's by value, since Hadoop works this way otherwise. For example you might assume you can modify the state of a key or value object in the chained `Mapper` and be very surprised that the `Reducer` before it observes that change. (I think this is bad design though.)

So this argument controls whether Hadoop just serializes and deserializes the object anyway -- basically, creates a clone via serialization. It's extra work.

The `byValue` argument is not present in the newer Hadoop APIs. The default is `true` and you might stick with that unless you know better. If you are sure you do not modify the key/value object state, you can safely use `false` and gain a little speed with passing by reference.

Of course it's all a bit confusing since Java is always a pass-by-value language. But Objects are never passed by value, instead Object references are passed -- by value. Of course Java doesn't change in this regard.

Comment: I am honored that Mr. Owen found time to answer my question.That's a great answer. Could you also share some pointers where i can find some more details?